# Synapse Analytics - How to create linked service to SQL Serverless Database?

Tags: azure-synapse

Help

I have recently started using Synapse Analytics to tap into my Azure Data Storage Gen 2 Container.

I have many .csv and .parquet files and find it very useful to create - within Synapse Analytics - SQL Databases which point to folders that contain many .csv or .parquet files - which I can now query via SQL scripts.

However, how can I use these in the Data Copy Activity to via SQL script access the data and move them around...

I cannot seem to create a linked service to my new SQL database in the Synapse workspace:

how do i now create a linked service I can use via data copy activity to query my table or execute a custom query?

I can only see the master database?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to copy the data from serverless db Extrenal tables? to SQL database and you want to create a linked service for the serverless db is it correct?

Comment: hello am trying to read data via a copy activity (in azure data factory).

however this is an external table that was setup in synapse workspace sql database

Comment: i can create a linked service to synapse analytics using a sql username and password, but i cannot create a dataset that uses this synapse analytics linked service since it cannot read the underlying data from the azure storage gen 2 account

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#service-principal-authentication

Comment: Please check this and let me know if it helped

Comment: In this link you can see authenication as SPN

Comment: Hi no I am still struggling

Comment: I did manage to create a linked service and test it successfully in ADF.
But now I cannot create a dataset in ADF using the same Synapse Link, it is as though my sql user that hits the table cannot read the csv files stored in the azure storage container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work, likely not the most secure method.

But the trick was to create an SAS token in Azure Storage Account and use that when creating a SCOPED CREDENTIAL in the Synapse Analytics SQL Database:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '?sv=secret_key_here';
```

Then create an EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE, using the SCOPED Credential

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'my_datasource_name') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [my_datasource_name] 
    WITH (
        LOCATION = 'abfss://container_name@my_storage_account_name.dfs.core.windows.net' ,
        CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential
    )
```

Then create the external table using the data source created above:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[revenue] (
    [ID] bigint,
    [Client ID] bigint,
    [Amount] nvarchar(4000),
    [Type] nvarchar(4000),
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'source/*.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = [my_datasource_name],
    FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat]  
    )
```

FYI, this is my FILE_FORMAT:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_file_formats WHERE name = 'SynapseDelimitedTextFormat') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseDelimitedTextFormat] 
    WITH ( FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT ,
           FORMAT_OPTIONS (
             FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
             FIRST_ROW = 2,
             USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE
            ))
```

Comment: FYI, I used ChatGPT and slowly methodically asked it questions until it answered in a manner that I could practically implement.

Comment: The method you have tried will create the external table.
As your aim is to move the exteranal table data to sink

Comment: creating scoped cred,file format can be done even from the ADLS.
you can use the ADLS as source and use in copy activity

Comment: thanks, i wanted the ability to write a custom SQL script over the data stored in CSV files and now i can. thanks for your articles you also posted!